# No provider for serviceName! (componentName -> ServiceName)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am working on on **angular2** app. I have wrote a service to hold the data which will available through out the app on any component and update it.

here is my **GlobalDataService .ts**

```ts
import {Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
export class GlobalDataService {
    devIsLogin: boolean;
    dev: {};
    constructor(){
        this.devIsLogin=false;
    }
}
```

here is my bootstrap.ts

```ts
//import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';


import {AppComponent} from './components/app/app';
import {LoginService} from './services/loginService';
import {HttpService} from './services/httpServices';
import {GlobalDataService} from './services/GlobalDataService';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LoginService, HttpService, GlobalDataService]);
```

i have inject the **GlobalDataService** appComponent. to have single instance through out the application.

here is my appcomponent which try to access the globalDataService

```ts
import {Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';


import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home';
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login';
import {GlobalDataService} from '../../services/globalDataService';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/app/app.html',
    directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, NgIf]
})
export class AppComponent {
    devIsLogin: boolean;
    Dev: {};
    constructor(
        @Inject(Router) router: Router,
        @Inject(GlobalDataService) globalDataService: GlobalDataService
    ) {
        this.devIsLogin = false;
        globalDataService.devIsLogin=false;
        router.config([
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home' },
            { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, as: 'Login' }
        ]);
    }
}
```

but when i run my app its gives me error

[image]

Please correct what i missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Injectable()` annotation is missing from your service class

```ts
@Injectable() // <== missing
export class GlobalDataService {
    devIsLogin: boolean;
    dev: {};
    constructor(){
        this.devIsLogin=false;
    }
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

I would also remove `@Inject(GlobalDataService)`

> - When `@Inject()` is not present, [Injector] will use the type annotation of the parameter.

Comment: AFAIK the `@Inject(GlobalDataService)` annotation is redundant and could cause the problem.

Comment: Actually I don't know TS, I'm only using Dart. I wonder why you use different casing for the import of `'./services/GlobalDataService';` (`G`) in `bootstrap.ts` and your component.

Comment: i want only one instance of globalDataService which will share among all the component so that all component have same data and send data  from one component to other which are not parent child

Comment: If you only add to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [...])` (as you currently seem to do) then only one instance is created. Just don't add it as `providers:` anywhere else. I just wondered whether imports in TS are case-sensitive and it seems you're importing the same file with different casing.

Comment: but i am unable to understand how to access it on component

Comment: That looks fine how you do it currently.

Comment: Did you check the import as mentioned a few times in comments above?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using `GlobalDataService` in `LoginService` or `HttpService`. In that case try with putting it before `LoginService` and `HttpService`